# Postgres - compare to a null-timestamp

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

hi this is not really a problem i just want to understand why:

in postgres 9

```
this_.lastModified<=NULL
```

evaluates to true, why? lastModified is a timestamp without timezone

i think it would be more logic to interpret it like  "this_.lastModified<=0" which should evaluate to false if 0 is the lowest date and lastModified is a normal date

the complete query looks like this

```
select 
this_.*
from Entity this_ 
inner join DEntity d2_ on this_.device=d2_.id 
inner join u u1_ on this_.learner=u1_.userID 
inner join LMEntity m3_ on this_.method=m3_.id 
where u1_.userID='XXXX' and not (d2_.hardwareID='muh' and this_.timestamp='2013-08-02 00:00:00' and m3_.id=0 and this_.lastModified<=NULL)
```

Comment: No it does **not** "evaluate to true". It evaluates to "unknown". You will have to show us the full query you are using so that we can understand why you *think* it evaluates to true.

Comment: Why do you think it evaluates to `true`? Can you give an example row where you think it evaluates to true?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`this_.lastModified<=NULL` always evaluates to `null` and in this case your `where` clause is effectively:

```
where u1_.userID='XXXX' and not (d2_.hardwareID='muh' and this_.timestamp='2013-08-02 00:00:00' and m3_.id=0 and null)
```

if all of the comparisons here:

```
d2_.hardwareID='muh' and this_.timestamp='2013-08-02 00:00:00' and m3_.id=0
```

evaluates to 'true' the this whole clause evaluates to true:

```
where u1_.userID='XXXX' and not (true and null)
```

`true and null` evaluates to `null`

```
where u1_.userID='XXXX' and not null
```

`not null` evaluates to `null`

```
where u1_.userID='XXXX' and null
```

if `u1_.userID='XXXX'` equal `true`,  `u1_.userID='XXXX' and null` evaluates to `null`

and `where null` is equal to `where false`.

In short, the whole

```
where u1_.userID='XXXX' and not (d2_.hardwareID='muh' and this_.timestamp='2013-08-02 00:00:00' and m3_.id=0 and this_.lastModified<=NULL)
```

will evaluate to `null` if `u1_.userID='XXXX'` and all of `d2_.hardwareID='muh' and this_.timestamp='2013-08-02 00:00:00' and m3_.id=0` gives `true`